# Meteor/Iron-Router - How pass values from RouteController to template helper

Tags: meteor

If I have a route controller as follows:

```
add_departmentController = RouteController.extend({
    before: function(){
        var a = this.params._id;
        var b = 'abc'; 
    }
});
```

How can I access these values in a helper for the template

```
Template.add_department.helpers({
    SomeProperty: function () {
        //Here I need access to a or b from above
        //Would also be nice to access 'this' directly eg. this.params
    },
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the data function in the controller

```
add_departmentController = RouteController.extend({
    template: 'departmentTemplate',
    data: function(){
        return {_id: this.params._id};
    }
});
```

This "injects" the returned object of the data function as the data-context into your template.

[EDIT]

Template:
The {{_id}} comes directly from the data context, {{idFromHelper}} returns the _id from a template helper function.

```
<template name="departmentTemplate">

  {{_id}}

  {{idFromHelper}}

</template>
```

Helper:

```
Template.addDepartment.helpers({
    idFromHelper: function() {
        return this._id;
    }
})
```

Comment: I know about the data function in the controller but I don't know how to access it in either the helper function or the template - do you perhaps have an example of how to use/access the data object in both?

Comment: Hey @A_L I edited the answer, hope it helps. It should be really that easy, since the the data is right in the data-context of the Handlebars-Template and the template object itself. So you should be able to reference it via 'this._id'. If this does not work for you (but it should) you want to check if you can reference it via 'this.data._id'.

Comment: can the layoutTemplate also access the same data function?

Answer (score 13):

You can use `Router` object inside your client code to access the current controller:

```
Template.addDepartment.helpers({
  someHelper: function() {
    var controller = Router.current();
    // return the _id parameter or whatever
    return controller.params._id;
  }
});
```